# Как создать таблицу из полученных средних значений?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть фрейм данных `snaks`:

[image: Исходная таблица]

Мне нужно было найти средние значения по каждому столбцу. Я это нашла следующим кодом: `snaks.mean(axis=0)`.

Результат:

```
month           5.000000
Sku             5.444444
Amount         80.111111
Profit       8825.922222
Spasaniya       6.688889
Margin       2906.411111
dtype: float64
```

Как теперь получившиеся средние значения записать отдельной строкой в таблице?

---

Исходная таблица в текстовом виде:

```
    month   tt          group           subgroup                Sku Amount  Profit  Spasaniya   Margin
22  1   3511 LiJ_Py6i40BCKafl2  Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chokki H3 pbi6bi n MopenpoflyKTOB   4.0 17.0    1640.0  0.0     539.1
158 2   3511 LU_Py6i40BCK£w2    Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm M3 pbi6bi n MopenpoflyKTOB    5.0 55.0    5829.9  60.2        1948.1
295 3   3511 LiJ_Py6i40BCKafl2  Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm H3 pbi6bi n MopenpoflyKTOB    5.0 87.0    9602.0  0.0     3257.3
440 4   3511 LU_Py6i40BCK£w2    Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm H3 pbi6bi n MopenpoflyKTOB    5.0 124.0   12589.8 0.0     4066.2
589 5   3511 W_Py6LiOBCKafl2    Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm H3 pbi6bi n MopenpoflyKTOB    6.0 97.0    10665.0 0.0     3581.3
727 6   3511 LU_Py6i40BCK£w2    Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm M3 pbi6bi m MopenpoflyKTOB    6.0 106.0   12465.8 0.0     4036.1
871 7   3511 LiJ_Py6i40BCKafl2  Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm M3 pbi6bi m MopenpoflyKTOB    6.0 101.0   11361.6 0.0     3734.9
1014    8   3511 LU_Py6i40BCK£w2    Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm M3 pbi6bi m MopenpoflyKTOB    6.0 82.0    9272.3  0.0     3002.1
1159    9   3511 Lil_Py6i40BCKafl2  Pbi6a. MopenpoflyKTbi   Chskm M3 pbi6bi m MopenpoflyKTOB    6.0 52.0    6006.9  0.0     1992.6
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Поправте пожалуйста исходную таблицу, OCR программы плохо распознают смесь языков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
     a    b    c    d
0   xx   11   12  aaa
1  yyy  110  120  bbb
2   zz  111  122  ccc
```

Решение:

```
In [17]: res = df.append(df.mean(), ignore_index=True)
```

Результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]:
     a           b           c    d
0   xx   11.000000   12.000000  aaa
1  yyy  110.000000  120.000000  bbb
2   zz  111.000000  122.000000  ccc
3  NaN   77.333333   84.666667  NaN
```

Comment: большое спасибо! Все получилось)

Comment: @Olga, всегда рад помочь (: